# How to read large file by blocks with n length

Tags: go

I want to read and split large text file (near 3GB) to blocks with n symbols length. I was trying to read file and split using runes, but it takes a lot of memory.

```
func SplitSubN(s string, n int) []string {
    sub := ""
    subs := []string{}
    runes := bytes.Runes([]byte(s))
    l := len(runes)
    for i, r := range runes {
        sub = sub + string(r)
        if (i+1)%n == 0 {
            subs = append(subs, sub)
            sub = ""
        } else if (i + 1) == l {
            subs = append(subs, sub)
        }
    }
    return subs
}
```

I suppose it can be done in smarter way, like a phased reading of blocks of a certain length from file, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Not only splitting takes a lot of memory, but you're reading the whole file into memory before this. You need to read the file in a streaming fashion. Using Reader's [ReadRune](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadRune), for example.

Comment: It would be easier if you needed n bytes, not n symbols - then you could use a loop with [io.ReadFull](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull) into a n-bytes slice. For your requirement of n runes, the easiest way is to use a loop with n calls of [bufio.ReadRune](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadRune) as @SergioTulentsev suggested, not superoptimal for many n, but valid.

Comment: By the way, a convenient way to avoid reading everything into memory while keeping the code short and clean, is to read chunks and put the result into a string channel, then the other goroutine can read channel via `for s := range channel` but memory allocation is keeping one chunk at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Scan for [rune start](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#RuneStart) bytes and split based on that. This eliminates all allocations within the function except for the allocation of the result slice.

```
func SplitSubN(s string, n int) []string {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    m := 0
    i := 0
    j := 1
    var result []string
    for ; j < len(s); j++ {
        if utf8.RuneStart(s[j]) {
            if (m+1)%n == 0 {
                result = append(result, s[i:j])
                i = j
            }
            m++
        }
    }
    if j > i {
        result = append(result, s[i:j])
    }
    return result

}
```

The API specified in the question requires that the application allocate memory when converting the []byte read from the file to a string. This allocation can be avoided by changing the function to work on bytes:

```
func SplitSubN(s []byte, n int) [][]byte {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    m := 0
    i := 0
    j := 1
    var result [][]byte
    for ; j < len(s); j++ {
        if utf8.RuneStart(s[j]) {
            if (m+1)%n == 0 {
                result = append(result, s[i:j])
                i = j
            }
            m++
        }
    }
    if j > i {
        result = append(result, s[i:j])
    }
    return result

}
```

Both of these functions require that the application slurp the entire file into memory.  I assume that's OK because the function in the question does as well.  If you only need to process one chunk at a time, then the above code be be adapted to scan as the file is read incrementally.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But could you tell me the name of the method to read file incrementally? I want to read about it.

Comment: Use the File.Read method to read part of a file.  Do you need exactly N runes, or is it ok to read M bytes rounded to the nearest rune? What is the value of N?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the most interesting part is not parsing chunk itself but rather handling characters overlapping.

For example, if you read from a file say in chunks of `N` bytes but last multi-byte char is read partially (the remainder will be read in the next iteration).

Here is a solution that reads a text file by given chunks and handles characters overlapping in async manner:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    data, err := ReadInChunks("testfile", 1024*16)

    competed := false
    for ; !competed; {
        select {
        case next := <-data:
            if next == nil {
                competed = true
                break
            }
            fmt.Printf(string(next))
        case e := <-err:
            if e != nil {
                log.Fatalf("error: %s", e)
            }
        }
    }
}

func ReadInChunks(path string, readChunkSize int) (data chan []rune, err chan error) {
    var readChanel = make(chan []rune)
    var errorChanel = make(chan error)

    onDone := func() {
        close(readChanel)
        close(errorChanel)
    }

    onError := func(err error) {
        errorChanel <- err
        onDone()
    }

    go func() {
        if _, err := os.Stat(path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
            onError(fmt.Errorf("file [%s] does not exist", path))
            return
        }

        f, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            onError(err)
            return
        }
        defer f.Close()

        readBuf := make([]byte, readChunkSize)
        reminder := 0

        for {
            read, err := f.Read(readBuf[reminder:])
            if err == io.EOF {
                onDone()
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                onError(err)
            }

            runes, parsed := runes(readBuf[:reminder+read])
            if reminder = readChunkSize - parsed; reminder > 0 {
                copy(readBuf[:reminder], readBuf[readChunkSize-reminder:])
            }

            if len(runes) > 0 {
                readChanel <- runes
            }
        }
    }()

    return readChanel, errorChanel
}

func runes(nextBuffer []byte) ([]rune, int) {
    t := make([]rune, utf8.RuneCount(nextBuffer))
    i := 0
    var size = len(nextBuffer)
    var read = 0
    for len(nextBuffer) > 0 {
        r, l := utf8.DecodeRune(nextBuffer)
        runeLen := utf8.RuneLen(r)
        if read+runeLen > size {
            break
        }
        read += runeLen
        t[i] = r
        i++
        nextBuffer = nextBuffer[l:]
    }
    return t[:i], read
}
```

It can be greatly simplified if the file is ACSII.

Alternativly, if you need to support unicode you can play aroud UTF-32 (which has fixed length) or UTF-16 (if you don't need to handle >2-bytes, you can treat it as fixed-size as well)